# How to fill zeroes of a day with the previous day values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some days with complete zeroes and would like to replace them with the previous day values as shown here.

Input

```
       count
2020-02-01 00:00:00     12
2020-02-01 00:01:00     3
2020-02-01 00:02:00     14
2020-02-01 00:03:00     0
2020-02-01 00:04:00     22
2020-02-02 00:00:00     0
2020-02-02 00:01:00     0
2020-02-02 00:02:00     0
2020-02-02 00:03:00     0
2020-02-02 00:04:00     0
2020-02-03 00:00:00     2
2020-02-03 00:01:00     4
2020-02-03 00:02:00     1
2020-02-03 00:03:00     0
2020-02-03 00:04:00     22
```

Output

```
        count
2020-02-01 00:00:00     12
2020-02-01 00:01:00     3
2020-02-01 00:02:00     14
2020-02-01 00:03:00     0
2020-02-01 00:04:00     22
2020-02-02 00:00:00     12
2020-02-02 00:01:00     3
2020-02-02 00:02:00     14
2020-02-02 00:03:00     0
2020-02-02 00:04:00     22
2020-02-03 00:00:00     2
2020-02-03 00:01:00     4
2020-02-03 00:02:00     1
2020-02-03 00:03:00     0
2020-02-03 00:04:00     22
```

I was trying something like this but couldn't solve it.

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.reset_index()

df['Date'] = df['index'].dt.date
df['Time'] = df['index'].dt.time


df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time), inplace=True)
for ind in df[df.count.eq(0)].index:
    df.loc[ind, 'count'] = df.loc[ind - pd.Timedelta('1D'), 'count']
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: look into `ffill` and `bfill` which should fill missing values with previous values or next values.

Comment: They don't consider days into account. They just fill values from a previous time or later time.

Comment: you want to fill only when all 0 for the day? or forexample if you have 1 instead of 0 in the first day hour=3, would you fill day 3 hour 3 with 1 as well?

Comment: Good question! Can I have both options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `mask` to replace the 0s with nan, then `groupby` the time in the DatetimeIndex and `ffill`, then `fillna` with 0 to complete the time where no value before.

```
df_ = (df.mask(df.eq(0))
         .groupby(df.index.time)
         .ffill() #add the parameter limit=1 if you want to fill only one day after
         .fillna(0)
      )
print (df_)
                     count
2020-02-01 00:00:00   12.0
2020-02-01 00:01:00    3.0
2020-02-01 00:02:00   14.0
2020-02-01 00:03:00    0.0
2020-02-01 00:04:00   22.0
2020-02-02 00:00:00   12.0
2020-02-02 00:01:00    3.0
2020-02-02 00:02:00   14.0
2020-02-02 00:03:00    0.0
2020-02-02 00:04:00   22.0
2020-02-03 00:00:00    2.0
2020-02-03 00:01:00    4.0
2020-02-03 00:02:00    1.0
2020-02-03 00:03:00    0.0
2020-02-03 00:04:00   22.0
```

If you want to fill with previous values **ONLY** if all values of the day are 0, then in `mask` above, change `df.eq(0)` by `df['count'].eq(0).groupby(df.index.date).transform('all')`. In this case it does not change the result.

If you want to fill with the average of the same time until the current time, then you can use `expanding` like:

```
(df.mask(df.eq(0))
   .groupby(df.index.time)
   .expanding().mean()
   .fillna(0)
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()
)
```

Comment: That works. haha. Is it possible choose days with X% of the day is zeroes instead of the day with all zeroes? If it is complicated don't need to answer :). I already took so much time from you.

Comment: @ferrelwill in the mask, you can do `(df['count'].eq(0) & df['count'].eq(0).groupby(df.index.day).transform('mean')>X)` where X is a number between 0 and 1

Comment: I am confused. The values should vary across every minute and I want to keep the same time structure as the previous non-zero day. For ex: On 17th at 2 PM if the count is 100 then it should be the same on 18th 2 PM. Every minute there are different values and therefore the count should not be flat. Hope that is clear.

Comment: Agreed but 18th Feb sum is way lower than 17th.  Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: I see the output doesn't have a timestamp. It only has a date. That's why the plot has a flat trend. Is it possible to include both date and time in the index?

Comment: @ferrelwill yes, it is just because we used df_.groupby(df_.index.date).sum() to compare and in the plot, but if you use df_.plot() (you used another notation but I hope it makes sense) then you will see more spikes and intra day variation